# How is revocation of a root certificate handled?

Tags: security, ssl, cryptography, certificate

There are several reasons to revoke a certificate, the most popular one being compromise of the private key.

My question is:
What happens if there is a need to revoke the certificate of a certificate authority?

Does this mean that **all** the certificates it has signed should be considered revoked?
This seems reasonable, since the CA will be issued a new certificate hence a new key-pair.

On the other hand, what would be the process to revoke and reissue possibly hundreds of certificates the specific CA has already issued so far?

I am confused on the consequences of revoking a CA certificate.
Could someone please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 12):

You can't revoke a trusted (e.g. Root CA) certificate, because it is self-signed by the CA and therefore there is no trusted mechanism by which to verify a CRL.  If a root CA is compromised it is very bad :-).  You have to manually remove the CA from your store (or this can happen by browser or OS updates if those root certs were part of those distributions).

Revoking a CA whose certificate was issued by one of the root CAs means that all the certificates that CA has issued are no longer valid. This happens during path processing, we start at the certificate we are trying to verify and then build a path all the way to a trusted root. Each certificate in that path should have their various path constraints checked, and a CRL (or other mechanism) should be used to determine whether they have been revoked. If any certificate fails then the whole path is considered invalid.

So the short answer is, yes. If the CA certificate is revoked, all certificates it issued (and so on down the path) should be considered invalid.

Comment: So in the path building the path is build from the target certificate up to the trust anchor.The revocation checking then is done the other way round then? From the top (excluding trust anchor) to the target certificate?

Comment: Also what would be the process (practically) to re-issue all the certificates that CA has issued?

Comment: No CRL processing is done from the target/end-entity certificate to the root as you do path processing.  The only practical way to reissue all the certificates is to revoke the CA, create a new CA certificate and then issue new certificates for every entity.  It's a catastrophic failure, and for this reason CA's should try not to get their certs revoked :-).

Comment: The CRL to revoke the root certificate could be signed by the root certificate itself. It is the same way as PGP public keys are revoked.

Answer (score 6):

Revoking a certificate means the following: "although the contents of that certificate look fine, the certificate should not be used". It is a way to "cancel" the cryptographic signature on the certificate.

Before using a certificate (i.e. using the public key contained in the certificate, for instance as part of a SSL connection), the certificate must be validated, which means that the signature on the certificate must be verified relatively to the public key contained in a CA certificate. This implies *using* the CA certificate, so the signature on *that* certificate must also be verified, and so on, up to a "root CA", also known as "trust anchor", which is assumed to be always verified (it is hardcoded in whatever software is doing the verification).

If a CA certificate is revoked then it cannot be used (that's the point of revoking a certificate: so that it is not used anymore). In particular, certificate validation should not be able to use that CA certificate anymore. The certificates which that CA issued are *not* revoked: possibly, they may be verifiable with *another* CA certificate which contains the same key: a CA certificate is like any other certificate, it binds a name with a public key; nothing prevents the existence of several distinct certificates which assert that binding, and this is a normal situation in the case of "bridge CA" (mostly used so that some certificates may be verified relatively to several trust anchors). Of course, *if* the CA certificate is revoked because the CA private key was stolen, then the sensible course of action is to revoke *all* certificates issued *to* that CA, and the certificates issued *by* that CA will be no longer verifiable by anybody.

So, to sum up, revoking a CA certificate does not revoke all certificates issued by that CA, but it prevents verifying those certificates through that CA.

Comment: 1)So the consequense is that the validation path breaks, and so the issued certificate will be "useless"? 2)I did not know there was a case where
we could have the same public key with multiple certificates.In this case, the public key is the same but I assume the subject dn is different?

Comment: @user384706: 1) Yes. 2) Hopefully not ! The certificate binds a key to a name which should be _the_ key owner. What you could have is the same key and the same subject DN, but distinct issuer DN (this means that two CA are asserting "this is Bob's public key" for the same Bob and the same key).

Comment: In this case, there are multiple validation paths, right?.So in a simplified question, if for example there is a check if a certificate X has been revoked, and using certificate X and it's signing certificate Y only in the validation path, is there a case that a certificate higher in the chain could be revoked, but we get e.g. from the OCSP responder that the certificate X is still ok?

Comment: @user384706: an OCSP response only means that a given certificate is "not revoked", but does not replace validation. To consider a certificate as valid, it must be signed by a _valid_ CA certificate, _and_ revocation status check must respond "not revoked". If a certificate "higher in the chain" is revoked then it cannot be used, in particular not to validate the rest of the chain. The revocation status of 'X' is thus irrelevant: 'X' should first be verified to be signed by a valid CA public key, and this cannot happen with a revoked certificate higher in the chain.

Comment: @ThomasPornin I am suggesting an improvement to this answer, please click [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288431/appeal-against-rejected-edit) for details.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the CA certificate is revoked, it's issued certificates should no longer be considered 'signed'.

Comment: So in a deployment where the compromized CA has issued hundrends of certificates, what would be the process to renew these?Is there a standard approach?